# Pervasive ODBC Client Interface

Tags: c#, odbc

I have been working on small tool for inspecting customers from ODBC database. Tool seems to be working on my computer with drivers installed (Actian PSQL) but I just started to wonder is it possible to spread this tool to other users. However I have found out that you need Pervasive ODBC Client Interface Unicode driver for that. It looks like otherwise connection can't be established.

Do anyone have any idea how this can be done? Is it so that there should be some executable file with drivers inside of it or there is some other way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to the Pervasive ODBC driver, it must be installed on the machine where the application is running.  If your target audience has a Pervasive database, they will have the Pervasive ODBC driver.  In addition, the ODBC driver is just a small part of the Pervasive product.  For example, the ODBC driver can't open files directly.  The ODBC driver connects to the engine which opens the files.  You can't use the ODBC driver without an engine to open the files and you can't use the ODBC driver from an application without the driver.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I guess the only way to get this working is to install this driver to all computer's where tool should be used?

Comment: Installing just the driver won't help.  There will still need to be an engine.  And it is not a free product.   If you are targetting the Pervasive engine and users that already have a Pervasive engine, they should already have the ODBC driver.

Comment: How do I know if I have the engine installed?

Comment: @user2511599 Better to ask that question as a new question rather than add on to this question.  Short answer would be the engine is installed where the Pervasive / Actian data is located.